# Display date one day before in grid view using c# compared to system date?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ext.net

When I Change the system time Zone then automatically changed in grid date column to one day before compared to system date but in database it doesn't changed.
for example in database, the time is 02/01/2016 after changing system timezone it displays one day before i.e 01/01/2016 in grid but database date is not changing.

Comment: I think you must store all date in UTC in database. Use DateTime.UTCNow to store all time events and then while showing in the grids you can either convert before binding based on timezone or even more use jQuery plugins to show date based on user browser may be...

Comment: can you give any example using jquery plugins.. we are already used DateTime.UTCNow but it not working

Comment: moment.js may be of some help. What had you tried till now, can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the System TimeZone doesn't update the database values. You have to explicitly update it.

Comment: @Moons: Newbie cant comment until his reputation reaches 50.

Comment: Problem is not with database updation.Its while retreiving data from data base to grid view.The date is changed according to local timezone of the system.I need to stop that time zone conversion.

Comment: @Moons - I Don't have enough reputation(50+) to comment on others post.

Comment: @RahulHendawe yes you are correct. Bug congrats you are now able to comment and he will soon be :)